# Adding an item in a gridview collection makes the gridview disappear

Tags: multithreading, xaml, gridview, mvvm, observablecollection

Here's what my data look like :

- a view named **"View"**
- a view model named **"ViewModel"** used as a datasource by "View"
- a ObservableCollection of "Groups" named **"listGroups"**
- a ObservableCollection of "Sms" named **"listSms"**
- each "Groups" has its own "listSms"

The CollectionViewSource used by my grid view is sourced on "listGroups" and the itemPath is "listSms"

Everything is displayed just fine, my problem begins when i try to add a new sms to a group.
If i add the sms in "ViewModel", it works fine, the sms is added and i have the animation and stuff on "View".

It does not work when the adding method located in "ViewModel" is called by another thread despite the dispatch i use to do the add in the UI thread. The gridview just disappear.

I think its a thread issue but i don't know why, maybe the CoreDispatcherPriority used to do the add should'nt by set to Normal ?

If you think of anything, shoot

Thanks